# CSS - max-height doesn't work for printing image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a web application where you can draw an image. When you print the the website, there should only be the image, and it should use as much space as possible on one page.

My problem: if the image is much higher than wide, it still uses the full width and the lower edge is cut off or is on a second page! Firefox also cuts off about 2% of the image at the right edge. How can I solve this problem using css? Or is this only possible with JavaScript?

```
@media print {

  #content {
    display:none;
  }

  #canvas {
    position:absolute;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    margin:0px;
  }
}
```

**Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gh28n/6/**

Comment: Have you tried to set width:100%; and height:auto; ?

Comment: Now I have; it doesn't work!

Comment: Ah sorry, max-width:100% and height:auto; (my bad)

Comment: no, still doesn't work.

Comment: does `overflow: hidden;` work on print?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to set a fixed with so large it can fit any paper, and set the max-width to 100% so it will always be scaled down, and height to auto to maintain the aspect ratio, like so:

```
    #canvas {
        width: 9999em;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

As for the clipping on the edge, removing the `position: absolute` fixed it.

edit: added `max-height: 100%;`

Comment: doesn't work! The image is scaled down to fit into the page, but the aspect ratio gets lost: every image is printed with a height of exactly 100% and with a width of exactly 100%!

Comment: Ah, I only experimented with a solid color canvas – do you have a fiddle to experiment with? I guess this will work if you account for the variable aspect ratio in your canvas code: you need to do this anyway, since the canvas element doesn't have inherent dimensions based on the content in a way the <img> element has.

Comment: Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gh28n/4/ - The problem with this website is, I don't know how to print just the result.